# Best place to farm money in Borderlands 2

Tags: borderlands-2

There are several "badass rank" challenges that involve hoarding money or using money to buy weapons.

Where are the most effective places to farm or make money in Pandora?

Answer (score 6):

Go to the fridge and farm the crystalisk, it's pretty good for money.

Answer (score 5):

Really good way to farm money is during the Mission to save Roland. Just complete that mission over several times and you can build up a fortune of around 100,000+.

Another good way to farm is to use the Slot Machines in Sanctuary, but the trick to it is, make sure you have a full party. For each time you win money on the slot machine, everyone else in your party does as well. Just cycle out between 2 people and keep gambling and selling any weapon that you aren't interested in.

My party made around 50,000 in about 2 hours, not too mention, we got some pretty fantastic weapons.

Comment: Might be useful to note that the slot machines get more expensive as you level up so unless you're winning or getting decent weapons you might lose money in the long run. Haven't checked the numbers but this may be offset by generally having more money at higher levels anyway...

Comment: @Alex It scales with levels but the rewards you receive back also scale with level. Solo you can basically make back the money you spend. In groups of 4 you easily make far more than you spend, as well as you end up with 100s (yes, 100s) of eridium and very good guns.

Answer (score 5):

Run through thousand cuts, ignoring all mobs en route, to bunker.  Bunker is an unpopulated zone home only to the boss BUNK3R, who is easy to beat using a corrosive sniper.  On normal he and his loot-splosion are lvl 26 and he yields 10k xp,  erridium, $$, and all rarity of items including a legendary shield.  There is a save point and a vending machine in Bunker before encountering BUNK3R so merely sell all the stuff you don't want to use for around 20-30k per run and continuously save/exit/resume games to farm the boss to your heart's content.   If you're good (or a sniper specced assassin) you can down him in 3-4 minutes per run from the coveted area up top..  I spent more time looting him than fighting him since I look over each item and he drops around 30 things on average.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to get the final challenge level of For the Horde! is to farm bosses (kill them, get lots of guns, sell guns, repeat) at a high level. Unless you farm it earlier, you probably won't have the challenge by the end of playthrough 2 (I sure didn't, but never farmed). I recommend waiting and doing this during playthrough 2.5 unless you think you'll quit before then. You'll easily get a few hundred thousand per run this way and can max the challenge in under an hour.

The easiest way to farm bosses is to get yourself a The Bee shield; Hunter Hellquist drops them; he respawns after the mission This Just In is completed after the end of the game. Kill him, quit, restart, kill him again until he drops it. The shield gives overpowered amp damage. Use The Bee and pretty much any Shotgun and you can easily slaughter Terramourphous, Warrior or BNK3R repeatedly (or any other boss). Alternately Assassins can one-shot kill BNK3R due to the Bore skill being bugged; it hits him repeatedly and does insane damage with a single shot.

Just pick up as much loot as you can carry and sell it, then save & quit, rinse repeat. At level 50 you'll be finding blue weapons worth $100k+, tons of greens worth at least $20k and maybe even some purple equipment you want to keep.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to the fridge and do this route, kill snow white parody boss, loot 2 chests in the tunnels behind her, kill the boss raider thingy from the goliath quest. pickup everything, save repeat. you can skip all the normal creature if you like and just kill the bosses. This way you get to do more of them. 7k Each trip and each trip is about 3 minutes long. Managed to farm sledges shotgun too. Happy Hunting!

Answer (score 1):

Preface: It is not necessary to farm money, one will never run out.

It's all about selling guns! Max out backpack asap. Sell expensive loot. After finishing the final playthrough just farm some bosses. I have been killing the Warrior for 6 hours now, trying to get the conference call. In that time I have amassed 24 million by collecting purple, blue and green guns dropped.

Tip: Farm the bosses that also drop legionaries you are interested in, two birds with one stone.

Have fun!

Comment: I did this after play-through #2. Just quit and save before leaving the vault and when you continue it is just before the warrior battle. Very fast, and he drops tons of valuable stuff. I think I got about 2 million in 45 mins, but really, there is no need for money in the game, so its all about looking for good upgrades. The best part about this is that the warrior dies faster every time you find an upgraded weapon, and second wind kills are trivial because the Rakks have very low health.

Answer (score 1):

Once you beat the game, farm on The Warrior. Be sure to have powerful guns (Repeaters, Sniper, Rifles and SMGs are recommended). Once you make him spawn, head toward the exit but don't leave the area. He can't hurt you there (much) and you can easily target his weak spots from there.

Comment: Please put a spoiler warning in there..

Answer (score 1):

When farming money, equip the [**Pot O' Gold**](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Pot_O%27_Gold) shield. Its description:

> When damaged the shield has a small chance to drop money as well as shield boosters.

Answer (score 0):

Eh just cheat, dupe money with a friend its easy. Trade him all the money you have then dash board you have to be in his game though, you can do that as many times as you want until you have 99,999,999

it goes a lot faster if you give him all your money, go to dash board so it doesn't save, load up your game so he can give you all of his money plus the money you gave him then he dash boards so it doesn't save then join his and keep repeating its the fastest way.

Hold b to trade for xbox lol

also i know this was more for legit farming but i just wanted anyone that was interested to know its there. I hope people don't mind too much as it isn't really a game breaking glitch.